# How to reverse dictionary items and list keys grouped by common values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to group by the common values:

```
init_dict = {'00001': 'string1', '00002': 'string2', '00003': 'string1', '00004': 'string3', '00005': 'string2'}
```

I want to create a new dictionary that groups the values and lists the keys like this:

```
new_dict = {'string1': ['00001', '00003'], 'string2':['00002', '00004'], 'string3': ['00004']}
```

I tried many things and this is the closest I can get.

```
lookup = 'string1'
all_keys = []
for k, v in init_dict.items():
  if v == lookup:
    all_keys.append(k)
print(all_keys)
```

This produces the first list: `['00001', '00003']` so I thought I could somehow loop through a list of `lookup` values but can't since I'm working with strings. Is there a way to do this and is there a way that is relatively efficient because my initial dictionary has 53,000 items in it. Any help would be much appreciated as I've been trying different things for hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), specifying a `list` as default argument, and append the corresponding values from the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d =  defaultdict(list)
for k,v in init_dict.items():
    d[v].append(k)
```

---

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list,
            {'string1': ['00001', '00003'],
             'string2': ['00002', '00005'],
             'string3': ['00004']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict`

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in init_dict.items():
    result[v].append(k)
```

or `itertools.groupby`

```
result = {k: [x[0] for x in v] for k, v in
          groupby(sorted(init_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]), key=lambda kv: kv[1])}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a normal `dict` (instead of `defaultdict`):

```py
new_dict = {}
for key, val in init_dict.items():
    if val in new_dict:
        new_dict[val].append(key)
    else:
        new_dict[val] = []
        new_dict[val].append(key)
```

Output:

```py
new_dict = {'string1': ['00001', '00003'],
            'string2': ['00002', '00005'], 
            'string3': ['00004']}
```